# CreditCardPayment with V3 Not Supported?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

When sending a Credit Card Payment (See REQUEST for details) to the V3 of the IPP Api's I receive the following error :

```
<Message>Feature Not Supported Error</Message>
<Detail>Feature Not Supported Error : CreditCardPayment</Detail>
```

The frustrating part is that I was specifically told in a former post [Sales Receipt Process Credit Card Payment QBO V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067969/sales-receipt-process-credit-card-payment-qbo-v2) that CreditCardPayment is not supported in V2 but is supported in V3 of the APIs. When I mock this same request for the V2 Payment API I receive an expected invalid CC response, which appears to indicate that CreditCards can be processed with the V2 Payment API.  Any help would be extremely appreciated.

```
REQUEST ::
 <Payment>
      <CustomerRef>1027</CustomerRef>
<Line>
    <<LineNum>1</LineNum>
    <Amount>1.64</Amount>
</Line>
<PaymentMethodRef>13</PaymentMethodRef>
<PaymentType>CreditCard</PaymentType>
<CreditCardPayment>
    <CreditCardChargeInfo>
        <Number>1234567890123456</Number>
        <Type>MasterCard</Type>
        <NameOnAcct>Fake User</NameOnAcct>
        <BillAddrStreet>111 Fake St SE</BillAddrStreet>
        <CCTxnMode>CardPresent</CCTxnMode>
        <CCTxnType>Charge</CCTxnType>
        <CcExpirMn>01</CcExpirMn>
        <CcExpirYr>14</CcExpirYr>
        <ZipCode>11155</ZipCode>
        <Cvv>123</Cvv>
    </CreditCardChargeInfo>
</CreditCardPayment>
<ProcessPayment>true</ProcessPayment>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Intuit Partner Platform v3 APIs are still in beta, so not everything is supported yet.

<strike>If you look at Intuit's recent blog post:</strike>

- http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/V3

You'll see a link to their roadmap in PDF format under the video. The roadmap indicates that Payments will be supported in the *July* release of the v3 data services.

**UPDATE**:  Look at Intuit's documentation for what is supported, and what isn't:

- [Intuit's v3 docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services)

So, it *will* be available in v3 data services, it *just isn't available yet*. Coming soon!

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services